# Change bg color/give border to current day

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, border

I would really love to know how you can change a table row, with use of the current time, to highlight/change bg color.

I have 7 days in a table for opening times of a shop, and I want to highlight the current day in a different color. Just a cosmetic touch I'd like to implement. Any help is appreciated.

I am not a coder but my thought proces is that getting the current time is not enough; it must be used to match any of the weekdays by an id or so, like today is sunday, the text in the row is 'sunday' as well, so it knows it has to change that TD's bg color.

Is this possible at all? Any help is appreciated. :)

Answer (score 1):

Indeed you have to get the current day in javascript following this :
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getday.asp

Then you just have to get the corresponding cells and setting a specific css class like so :

```js
var d = new Date();
var n = d.getDay();

document.getElementById(n).className = "bg";
```

```css
.bg{
  background-color:#939393;
  border:solid 1px;
}
```

```html
<table style="border:solid 1px">
  <tr>
    <td id="0">Sunday</td>
    <td id="1">Monday</td>
    <td id="2">Tuesday</td>
    <td id="3">Wednesday</td>
    <td id="4">Thursday</td>
    <td id="5">Friday</td>
    <td id="6">Saturday</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I liked the simplest solution.

Comment: Thank you so much. Might start to grasp the logic behind doing things like this myself later on. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<table>
  <tr><td>Sunday</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Tuesday</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Wednesday</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Thursday</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Friday</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Saturday</td></tr>
</table>
```

// Jquery

```
$(function(){
  var weekday = ["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"];
  var date = new Date();
  var currentDay = weekday[date.getDay()];

  $('table td').each(function() {
    if($(this).html() == currentDay)
      $(this).addClass('active');
  });

})

//CSS

table tr td{
  border: 1px solid gray;
  background-color: #082768;
  color: #fff;
}
table tr td.active{
  background-color: red;
  color: #fff;
}
```

Working Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/d2tfo790/1/